# Why must the converging lens have a shorter focal length than the diverging lens if the latter focal length is to be determined by combining them

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

Why must the converging lens have a shorter focal length than the diverging lens if the latter focal length is to be determined by combining them?

When we had done the experiment in lab we did mechanically with out understanding.
But we had to note this precaution.

Answer (score 1):

With that constraint on the focal lengths the combination of the two lenses will be acting as a converging lens which will produce a real image otherwise the image would be virtual.